# I cannot change FontSize when trying to modify text style in docx by using DocumentFormat dll

Tags: openxml, docx

I looked at document.xml of my Template. There are "w:sz", "w:szCs", "w:lang", "w:b" inside for "w:p" and "w:r". I opened my doc.docx and only saved using DocumentFormat.dll. I see that appropriate text is in "w:t" element of a "w:r" of a "w:p" element and ect in the output. I see that the "w:r" has "w:rPr" and there are "w:b", "w:rFonts w:ascii w:cs, w:hAnsi" inside of it. "w:p" also has some properties. But "w:sz", "w:szCs" are not present. I tried to create RunStyleProperties and to prepend to an existing paragraph like in "[how can I change the font open xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956630/how-can-i-change-the-font-open-xml)" except i did not create a run, used foreach for existing paragrapths and runs. I tried to recreate methods that are described in "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-apply-a-style-to-a-paragraph-in-a-word-processing-document",but all my attempts were not effective. The fact is the style was not applied, the text style has some default values.