# Visual studio 2019 OpenXML polish letters

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, text, openxml

I'm trying to change basic font to "Arial" but if it is any polish symbol its change back to Calibri like on picture. Is is any way to apply it for polish symbols?

```
        Run run = new Run();
    RunProperties runProp = new RunProperties();
    Text textRun = new Text()
    {
        Text = text,
        Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve
    };
    runProp.Append(new RunFonts() { Ascii = EnumFonts.Arial.ToString() }, new FontSize());
        run.Append(runProp);
        run.Append(textRun);
```

[image]

Comment: From a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7958183/43846) - _"When you create documents with non-ascii characters you need to set additional properties on the RunFonts instance. For example if you want to set the font of a text with German umlauts **you need to change the HighAnsi property to your font (e.g. "Arial") as well.**"_

Comment: See the section "Volume Mapping" in the alsamixer man page, and the `-R`/`-M` options of amixer.